# Secondary tile text colour

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I know that MSDN states that this is not possible but is there any possible workaround/hack to change the colour of the text on a secondary tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to change font color is make text as your background image.

You can do like this:

put textBlock in a grid, change font color.

Render this grid to an image.

then save it to storage.

and set it as background image of tile.